# Split column of strings into matrix of strings using regex with colnames based on part of match

Tags: r, tidyr, tibble

I'm creating tibble from the gene descriptions in a FASTA file of protein coding sequences.  Here's some example data I want to process

```
seqDescriptions<- c( "lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624362.1_1 [locus_tag=SCO0001 ][db_xref=GeneID:1095448] [protein=hypothetical protein] [protein_id=NP_624362.1] [location=446..1123] [gbkey=CDS]", 
"lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624363.1_2 [locus_tag=SCO0002] [db_xref=GeneID:1095447] [protein=hypothetical protein] [protein_id=NP_624363.1] [location=1252..3813] [gbkey=CDS]",
"lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624364.1_3 [locus_tag=SCO0003] [db_xref=GeneID:1095446] [protein=DNA-binding protein] [protein_id=NP_624364.1] [location=3869..6220] [gbkey=CDS]",
"lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_631871.1_4 [locus_tag=SCO0004] [db_xref=GeneID:1095445] [protein=hypothetical protein] [protein_id=NP_631871.1] [location=6226..7173] [gbkey=CDS]")
```

I want to extract out the initial set of non-space characters in one column and then the information to the right of each tag.  Defining the tags manually

```
tagList <- c("locus_tag", "db_xref", "protein", "protein_id", "location", "gbkey")
```

My goal is to have a tibble that looks like this

```
# A tibble: 4 x 7
name                                  locus_tag    db_xref       protein ...
<chr>                                 <chr>         <chr>        <chr>  ...
"lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624362.1_1"  "SCO0001"  "GeneID:1095448" "hypothetical protein" ...
"lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624363.1_2"  "SCO0002"  "GeneID:1095447" "hypothetical protein" ...
```

The code below works, but I'd like to

1. See how to implement it in a `tidyr` way.
2. Have the columns are named using the value of `tag` as it's being constructed rather than after the fact.
3. Learn about any bioinformatic tools that could do this more directly, such as not having to manually define the tags.

.

```
fastaID <- sub("^(\\S+) .*", "\\1", seqDescriptions) 
seqTags <- sub("^\\S+ (.*)", "\\1", seqDescriptions)

dBase <- tibble(fasta_ID=fastaID)
for(tag in tagsUsed){
    tagPattern  <- paste0(".*\\[", tag, "=([^]]+).*")## Don't need to escape ']' with '^'
    dBase <- tibble::add_column(dBase, sub(tagPattern, "\\1", seqTags), .name_repair="unique" )
}

names(dBase) <- c("fasta_ID", tagsUsed)


tibble(tagsUsed))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of `tidyr::extract` we could do:

```r
d <- data.frame(
  seqDescriptions = seqDescriptions
)

tagList <- c("locus_tag", "db_xref", "protein", "protein_id", "location", "gbkey")
regex_tag <- lapply(tagList, function(.x) paste0("\\[", .x, "=(.*)\\]"))
regex_tag <- unlist(regex_tag)  
regex <- paste(c("^(\\S+)?", regex_tag), collapse = "\\s*")

library(tidyr)

d %>% 
  extract(seqDescriptions, into = c("name", tagList), regex)
#>                                name locus_tag        db_xref
#> 1 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624362.1_1  SCO0001  GeneID:1095448
#> 2 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624363.1_2   SCO0002 GeneID:1095447
#> 3 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624364.1_3   SCO0003 GeneID:1095446
#> 4 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_631871.1_4   SCO0004 GeneID:1095445
#>                protein  protein_id   location gbkey
#> 1 hypothetical protein NP_624362.1  446..1123   CDS
#> 2 hypothetical protein NP_624363.1 1252..3813   CDS
#> 3  DNA-binding protein NP_624364.1 3869..6220   CDS
#> 4 hypothetical protein NP_631871.1 6226..7173   CDS
```

Comment: This approach is clearest for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hybrid approach:

```r
# add "name" for the first column
tagList <- c("name", "locus_tag", "db_xref", "protein", "protein_id", "location", "gbkey")
rough <- strcapture("^([^]]+)\\s*(\\[[^]]+\\])\\s*(\\[[^]]+\\])\\s*(\\[[^]]+\\])\\s*(\\[[^]]+\\])\\s*(\\[[^]]+\\])\\s*(\\[[^]]+\\])",
                    seqDescriptions, proto=setNames(rep("", length(tagList)), tagList))
rough
#                                 name            locus_tag                  db_xref                        protein               protein_id              location       gbkey
# 1 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624362.1_1  [locus_tag=SCO0001 ] [db_xref=GeneID:1095448] [protein=hypothetical protein] [protein_id=NP_624362.1]  [location=446..1123] [gbkey=CDS]
# 2 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624363.1_2   [locus_tag=SCO0002] [db_xref=GeneID:1095447] [protein=hypothetical protein] [protein_id=NP_624363.1] [location=1252..3813] [gbkey=CDS]
# 3 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624364.1_3   [locus_tag=SCO0003] [db_xref=GeneID:1095446]  [protein=DNA-binding protein] [protein_id=NP_624364.1] [location=3869..6220] [gbkey=CDS]
# 4 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_631871.1_4   [locus_tag=SCO0004] [db_xref=GeneID:1095445] [protein=hypothetical protein] [protein_id=NP_631871.1] [location=6226..7173] [gbkey=CDS]
```

With that, we can clean it up:

```r
library(dplyr)
rough %>%
  mutate(across(-name, ~ trimws(gsub("^[^=]*=|\\]$", "", .))))
#                                 name locus_tag        db_xref              protein  protein_id   location gbkey
# 1 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624362.1_1    SCO0001 GeneID:1095448 hypothetical protein NP_624362.1  446..1123   CDS
# 2 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624363.1_2    SCO0002 GeneID:1095447 hypothetical protein NP_624363.1 1252..3813   CDS
# 3 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624364.1_3    SCO0003 GeneID:1095446  DNA-binding protein NP_624364.1 3869..6220   CDS
# 4 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_631871.1_4    SCO0004 GeneID:1095445 hypothetical protein NP_631871.1 6226..7173   CDS
```

Comment: Thanks, I find the strcapture() command a bit overwhelming in its complexity.

Comment: It's really just `(\\[[^]]+\\])` (start with a literal `[`, then some chars, then a literal `]`) repeated several times with `\\s*` optional spacers.

Answer (score 0):

without using much regex, we could do:

```
seqDescriptions %>%
  chartr(':=[]', '=:  ', .)%>%
  strsplit(' +')%>%
  map_df(~cbind.data.frame(grp = .x[1],
              grep(':', .x, value = TRUE) %>%
              textConnection() %>%
              read.dcf(fields = tagList)%>%
                chartr('=', ':', .)))

                               grp locus_tag        db_xref      protein  protein_id   location gbkey
1 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624362.1_1   SCO0001 GeneID:1095448 hypothetical NP_624362.1  446..1123   CDS
2 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624363.1_2   SCO0002 GeneID:1095447 hypothetical NP_624363.1 1252..3813   CDS
3 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_624364.1_3   SCO0003 GeneID:1095446  DNA-binding NP_624364.1 3869..6220   CDS
4 lcl|NC_003888.3_cds_NP_631871.1_4   SCO0004 GeneID:1095445 hypothetical NP_631871.1 6226..7173   CDS
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't know about map_df so am still wrapping my brain around this one.